# SOAP envelope for ksoap lib

Tags: java, android, sharepoint, soap

I write android client for sharepoint and use ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.8 lib. I've next code:

```
 public class AndroidWSDLKActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.193:30004/SPMobApp/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetList";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView lblResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                  // Set all input params   

        request.addProperty("listName", "Tasks");   

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                 // Enable the below property if consuming .Net service
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             try 
             {
                 List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
                 String authentication = android.util.Base64.encodeToString("LOGIN:PASS".getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);

                 headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authentication));

                 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


                 SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();


                 lblResult.setText(response.getProperty(0).toString());
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 lblResult.setText(e.getStackTrace().toString());
             }
```

In this step

> SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

in debug mode I have 2 errors

> Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete
>   Assignment
>
> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements

Whats wrong? Help me, plz

Comment: I think you are not getting soap response.you may getting response as json string

Comment: I think errors in a bad envelope, but I dont know how fix it or create сorrect envelope

Comment: I dont have response. In this row androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); I've a error An exception occurred: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException

Comment: use soapUI tool for getting soap response without excuting our code we can get the response of particlur web service.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AndroidWSDLKActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/";
    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.193:30004/SPMobApp/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetList";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetList";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView lblResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

                  // Set all input params   

        request.addProperty("listName", "Tasks");   

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                 // Enable the below property if consuming .Net service
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

             try 
             {
                 List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
                 String authentication = android.util.Base64.encodeToString("LOGIN:PASS".getBytes(), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);

                 headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authentication));

                 androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);


                 SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();


                 lblResult.setText(response.getProperty(0).toString());
             }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                 lblResult.setText(e.getStackTrace().toString());
             }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats new? } in the end? sorry, its my error in post, but its not help for my problem